# Access update sql thows error "Syntax error in query expression"

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to update my Students table with the details from the `Medicaldetails` table where there `MedRecID` matches. This is what I have:

```
UPDATE
    [Students]
INNER JOIN MedicalDetails
    ON ([Students].[Allergies]=MedicalDetails.[Allergies])
    AND [Students]].[EmergencyContact1]=MedicalDetails.[EmergencyContact1])
SET
    [Students].[Allergies] = [MedicalDetails].[Allergies],
    [Students].[EmergencyContact1] = [MedicalDetails].[EmergencyContact1]
WHERE
    [Students].[MedRecID] = [MedicalDetails].[MedRecID];
```

It keeps coming up with the error "syntax error in your expression".
Please help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see an extra closing parenthesis in your `JOIN` clause

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are updating:

```
Students.Allergies = MedicalDetails.Allergies,
Students.EmergencyContact1 = MedicalDetails.EmergencyContact1
```

You are also joining via:

```
ON (Students.Allergies = MedicalDetails.Allergies)
AND Students.EmergencyContact1 = MedicalDetails.EmergencyContact1)
```

This won't update anything since the values will be equal to each other.

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
UPDATE s
SET s.Allergies = m.Allergies, s.EmergencyContact1 = m.EmergencyContact1
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN MedicalDetails m ON s.MedRecID = m.MedRecID
```